# return value of ifelse from another vector via index

Tags: r, if-statement, indexing

I can't get my head around this problem regarding `ifelse`:

Say I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(0, 1:4, 1:4)
y <- letters[1:3]
```

When I do

```
ifelse(x==2, y[x], x)
```

I get

> "0" "1" "c" "3" "4" "1" "c" "3" "4"

However, it should return `"b"` at position 2 of vector `y`.
Why is `ifelse` doing that?

Comment: Not exactly sure what is happening with `ifelse` but since you want always 2nd position of `y` why not `ifelse(x == 2, y[2], x) ` ?

Comment: thanks but thats just a simple example to illustrate. I want the return index to be dynamic. plus I really would like to understand whats going on here

Comment: It returns c because: `which(x==2)` returns `3 and 7`. I don't know why it doesn't recycle 7 but chooses only 3. Perhaps because y is less than length 7.

Comment: y[x] returns this: "a" "b" "c" NA  "a" "b" "c" NA, I believe with 0 as a index, R is converting x from numeric to a factor and returning 2 becomes the third element. I can't find any documentation to support this theory.

Comment: It's not a factor though, it is a character vector (tested on a result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain this strange behaviour the source code of `ifelse` is helpful (see below).

As soon as you call `ifelse` the expressions passed as the arguments `test`, `yes` and `no` are evaluated resulting in:

```
Browse[2]> test
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Browse[2]> yes
[1] "a" "b" "c" NA  "a" "b" "c" NA 
Browse[2]> no
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Observe that `y[x]` uses the values of `x` to pick values from `y`
and the value 0 is empty (= ignored) , values above 3 are NA,
that is why the `yes´ argument becomes

> [1] "a" "b" "c" NA  "a" "b" "c" NA

The code line

```
ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok]
```

is then applied at the end and effectivly does update all `TRUE`-elements using the `test` logical vector:

```
yes[test]
```

which results in:

> [1] "c" "c"

being stored in the result indices 3 and 7

```
ans[test & ok]
```

**So the problem is using `y[x]` as second argument to `ifelse` + the non-intuitive `ifelse` behaviour to use a logical index to pick the "TRUE"-results from `y[x]`...**

Lesson learned: Avoid complicated `ifelse` logic, it has lot of side effects (eg. you may loose the correct data type or attributes).

```
# ifelse function
function (test, yes, no) 
{
  if (is.atomic(test)) {
    if (typeof(test) != "logical") 
      storage.mode(test) <- "logical"
    if (length(test) == 1 && is.null(attributes(test))) {
      if (is.na(test)) 
        return(NA)
      else if (test) {
        if (length(yes) == 1) {
          yat <- attributes(yes)
          if (is.null(yat) || (is.function(yes) && identical(names(yat), 
                                                             "srcref"))) 
            return(yes)
        }
      }
      else if (length(no) == 1) {
        nat <- attributes(no)
        if (is.null(nat) || (is.function(no) && identical(names(nat), 
                                                          "srcref"))) 
          return(no)
      }
    }
  }
  else test <- if (isS4(test)) 
    methods::as(test, "logical")
  else as.logical(test)
  ans <- test
  ok <- !(nas <- is.na(test))
  if (any(test[ok])) 
    ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & 
                                                           ok]
  if (any(!test[ok])) 
    ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test & 
                                                           ok]
  ans[nas] <- NA
  ans
}
```

Comment: Your use of the expression `x[y]` should probably be corrected to y[x]

Answer (score 1):

You are using 0 as an index in the first element so that is why the alignment is messed up.

```
y[x]

[1] "a" "b" "c" NA  "a" "b" "c" NA
```

So

```
> y[0]
character(0)
> y[1]
[1] "a"
> y[2]
[1] "b"
> y[3]
[1] "c"
```

So the length of y[x] is different than the length of x.

What you want is

```
> ifelse(x==2, y[x+1], x)
[1] "0" "1" "c" "3" "4" "1" "c" "3" "4"
```

but only if the first element is always 0.

**Old answer**
Because

```
x <- c(0, 1:4, 1:4)
```

returns

```
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

so `x==2`
returns

```
1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

so for `y = letters[1:3]`

```
ifelse(x==2, y[x], x)
```

You are going to get the letters in the third and seventh positions.

The documentation for ifelse says that if one vector is too short it will be recycled which you would expect to be
`c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a")`.

However when I try

```
ifelse(x==3, y[x], x)
```

I get

```
[1] "0" "1" "2" NA  "4" "1" "2" NA  "4"
```

Which tells me that the recycling is not working the way I would expect.
So that's the nominal reason you are getting the result.  The reason it works like that is something I don't know now, but if I figure it out I will add to this answer.  I suspect it has to do with the conversion to a string.

Just looking at `y[x]`  I get

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" NA  "a" "b" "c" NA
```

Which, by the way is only length 8 even though x is length 9.

So this really doesn't have to do with ifelse() at all, it is really about a different issue with recycling.

Answer (score 0):

**From Comment:** It returns `c` because: `which(x==2)` returns 3 and 7. I don't know why it doesn't recycle 7 but chooses only 3. Perhaps because y is less than length 7

Try:

```
ind<-which(x==2)
ind1<-ind[1]-1
ifelse(x==2,y[ind1],x)
[1] "0" "1" "b" "3" "4" "1" "b" "3" "4"
```

Here's an attempt to make a function:

```
dynamic_index<-function(ind,x,y){
  x<-x
  y<-y
  ind1<-which(x==ind)
 ind2<-ind1[1]-1
  ifelse(x==ind,y[ind2],x)
}
dynamic_index(2,x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result occurs lat way because the `==` function returns a vector of logicals:

```
x <- c(0, 1:4, 1:4)
y <- letters[1:3]

ifelse(x==2, y[x], x)

#look at x==2
x==2
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

It's a logical vector that has true in the third position, not the second so it is the third value of y that is selected. This also shows why the answer that references the behavior of `which` is incorrect.

Comment: Why is the behavior of `which` incorrect though? We see x==2 is TRUE twice that is at positions 3 and 7.

Comment: The `which` answer is incorrect because the source code of `ifelse` does not use `which` but is IMHO indirectly correct because the logical vector selects the values of these indices anyhow ;-)

Comment: Ah, true but it's still the same result regardless of what code the `ifelse` is using(in my humble and less experienced opinion). `which` is just a helper function(imhleo)

Comment: It was the statement " I don't know why it doesn't recycle 7" that made me think that using which was leading to certain puzzlement.

Answer (score -1):

x <- c(0, 1:4, 1:4)
y <- letters[1:3]

ifelse(x==2, y[x], x)

in ifelse it will check each position in x .if it is true then it will print y[x] position it means the position which was checked in x and that position of value in Y will be printed .it will check all the values in X