# Matching Intervals with Using Lookup Table in R

Tags: r, if-statement, indexing, lookup, intervals

I'm looking to use a lookup reference table that has Start and End intervals that align with a Standard (i.e. "Poor", "Average", etc.)

I have a data table where I'd like to create a new Standard column tagging the data value based on the interval it falls into on the lookup table. Below is a simplified example. My actual dataset is much larger and needs to be dynamic so I don't have to hard code or create many individual objects within the script.

```
lookup_df = data.frame("Standard" = c("Poor", "Below_Average", "Average", "Above_Average", "Good"),
                  "Start" = c(2,3,4,5,6), "End" = c(3,4,5,6,7))

col = c(1.5, 5.2, 4.1, 3.3, 9.6, 2.4)
```

I am attempting to use ifelse() and findInterval() to return the index from the lookup Standard column. I know the issue is the indexing part since findInterval returns 0s which can't be indexed. I tried to get around this by adding +1 to findInterval but that also didn't work. Here is what I've been trying:

```
ifelse(findInterval(col, lookup_df$End)+1 > 1, lookup_df$Standard[findInterval(col, lookup_df$End)+1], "Poor")

# [1] "Poor"          "Above_Average" "Average"       "Below_Average"
# [5] NA              "Poor"
```

My desired result is:

```
# [1] "Poor"          "Above_Average" "Average" "Below_Average"      
# [5] "Good"             "Poor"
```

I have tried using transform() from this example [Matching intervals with values in another table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117263/matching-intervals-with-values-in-another-table-in-r) but also wasn't able to get it to function properly.

The ifelse() indexing issue seems to align with this one [return value of ifelse from another vector via index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723789/return-value-of-ifelse-from-another-vector-via-index)

I'm guessing there is a simple solution here that I'm missing! Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT TO INCLUDE FINAL ANSWER**

This is the final solution I used based on R. Lima's solution to incorporate within dplyr:

```
lookup_vec = as.character(lookup_df$Standard)
names(lookup_vec) <- c("0", "1", "2", "3","4")

df = data.frame(col = c(1.5, 5.2, 4.1, 3.3, 9.6, 2.4))

df = df %>%
  mutate(Standard = stringr::str_replace_all(
    findInterval(col, lookup_df$Start[-1]), lookup_vec))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, although I have used str_replace_all() from package `stringr` instead of ifelse(). This functions handles the zero problem you mentioned.

There is probably a more elegant and faster way to do it, but this one does the trick.

```
# Defining the lookup reference object
lookup <- c("Poor", "Below_Average", "Average", "Above_Average", "Good")
names(lookup) <- c("0", "1", "2", "3","4")

# Defining your data frame
df <- data.frame(col = c(1.5, 5.2, 4.1, 3.3, 9.6, 2.4))

# Classifying the data and inserting into your data frame
df$classes <- stringr::str_replace_all(
  findInterval(df$col, c(3,4,5,6)), lookup)
df$classes

[1] "Poor"          "Above_Average" "Average"       "Below_Average" "Good"         
[6] "Poor"
```

Comment: That worked! I tweaked it  for my data and included the solution above. Thanks!